# how to insert duplicate record with different custom generated primary key SQL Server

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server, is there any easy way to achieve below scenario?

In one of my table, I have around 20 columns and primary key field where we put generated number (it's not autogenerated field). For a reason, we wanted to duplicate a record of certain primary key value with different primary key value.

So this could be my table data (assume KEYxxx is primary key field)

```
KEY001  AA1  AA2 AA3 AA4 ... AA20
KEY002  AA1  AA2 AA3 AA4 ... AA20
```

I am trying to insert a new row with same data: `KEY001` as `KEY002`

I have tried using this query here to do this, but failed, couldn't find a way to insert a new primary key value (`KEY002`) to this query.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (FIELD1, field2,...field20) 
    SELECT (FIELD1, field2,... field20) 
    WHERE field_primary_key = 'KEY001'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of specifying the PK column in the SELECT list, replace it with a literal value for the new key:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (FIELD_PK, field2,...field20) 
SELECT 'KEY002', field2,...field20
from mytable
where field_primary_key='KEY001'
```